# in xpage - invalid stream header: 1F8B0800

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

In the domino server log, i used to see this error more frequently,

But it does not not have any impact in the user side. They said they are not facing any issues.

What could be the issue?

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:   1F8B0800
at     com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.restoreView(AbstractStateManager.java:100)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:386)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:358)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:168)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1315)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Compon entModule.java:853)
at  com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentM odule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at  com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1299)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 1F8B0800
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:797)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:294)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectInputStream.<init> (AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:449)
at  com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.readSerializedView(AbstractSerializ ingStateManager.java:211)
at  com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.doRestoreView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:127)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doRestoreView(FileStateManager.java:249)
at  com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.restoreView(AbstractStateManager.java:93)
```

Comment: Is antivir installed on your server?

Answer (score 6):

2 years later, I found this while looking for 1F8B0800
1F8B is a magic signature for gzip.
So the stream is GZipped and is not expected to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical I/O Error and indicates that reading data back from disk didn't work properly. The JSF runtime persists state onto disk to conserve memory. Your problem could already occur when writing out didn't work, so the read gets "garbage" already.
In any case it points to a problem on your disk storage or eventual an imminent hardware failure. Can be hard to track at times. The usual suspects:

- As Frantisek suggested: AV software in paranoia mode: don't scan database directories on access (try that with your Oracle or mySQL and see them fail)
- Disk too fragmented
- Hardware inadequate, so I/O can't keep up (happens when userbase and/or db sizes grew beyond the original plan)
- faulty memory (so what goes out is broken already)

Check your server monitoring for spikes in I/O and review your hardware